# Google Sheets - Validation list to default on selection in another cell, but still provide drop-down options

Tags: google-sheets

I'm stuck on this one, and after a number of google searches am now wondering if I'm the only person who's ever tried to do this.

I have a google sheet that users are required to fill in. There is a drop-down selection option at the top, specifying the region the user needs the file for.
However, as the user gets down to the lines for the individual items required, some (a small number) may not be for the region selected at the top.

So what I'm trying to do is add the regions to the individual lines. The default for each line should be the region selected at the top, so this should show as pre-selected. But I want the user to be able to still click on a drop-down arrow and select a different region for a line.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: can you share an example of your sheet and give us your expected outcome? I would think you could use an IF statement, =IF(a2="John", C2 ="Yorkshire", "") to get around this.

Comment: I've created an example here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SyfQ1BMc9eAnev83lG2qVQ9ITGEsDuLPPRrvPXgrBmw/edit?usp=sharing   I've the region selected at the top, and want that selection to be the default selection in column A for all the lines. But if anyone wants to change that, I want them to be able to select any of the other regions as well. That's why a straight-out formula won't work, I do need them to be able to select the correct region via the drop-down

Comment: can you open up edit access  ?

Comment: I'd rather not, please feel free to create a copy for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I'm unsure of your expected outcome, your request is also not very clear -

What I've done is created a list via Data validation, however, if a user enters data into the adjacent column:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OsrQCUt-Urf_Gx8_l9CBZkaUlDc311-S-0csa9GAtCQ/edit?usp=sharing

also it's good practice to share an example of your workbook for others to edit and work on.

let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry, not really. What I need is for the selection made in cell B2 to show in column A on all lines. However, the cells on the lines should also contain a drop-down list allowing the user to change the regions line by line. Essentially, the selection in B2 should be the default populated on all the lines, but there should then be options to select different regions line by line